# Oracle Java web start silently dies (Ubuntu 12.10)

Tags: 12.10, java, oracle

Default OpenJDK 7 installed with Ubuntu 12.10 works fine. I have a few issues with a proprietary package I'm using and I need to test against Oracle's Java to see if it's specific to OpenJDK.

However, I cannot get Oracle's Java web start to work. The normal `java` command using a jar file works fine. But anything using `javaws` shows the splash screen and then does nothing. It even returns a 0 status code (success). No output, no errors, nothing. It just silently dies, even with `javaws -verbose`.

I have tried both 6 and 7 installer packages from `ppa:webupd8team/java`, 32bit and 64bit binary installers of 6 from the sun website. At this point OpenJDK is completely uninstalled. Still nothing.

This happens with every jnlp I can get my hands on, including this proprietary package, minecraft, and the Oracle JOGL test.

How can I get useful output out of `javaws`? Is there a log file somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/tracing_logging.html gives some info on logging and tracing output.

Annoyingly the command line options don't seem to work, but running `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/ControlPanel` and settings the options there works (log files are in `~/.java/deployment/log`)

Apparently there's a bug with Oracle Java 7u9 where it can't parse its arguments property. Manually editing the JNLP or downloading the referenced jar file and running that manually works. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u9-relnotes-1863279.html

In my case I had to remove `java-vm-args="-XX:MaxPermSize=128m"`